# Fitbit API Integration using oAuth 2.0 with chrome custom tabs in android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, fitbit, chrome-custom-tabs

I am building an Android app which integrates Fitbit to get user's data.

For integrating FitBit, I'm using Custom Chrome Tabs. When passing uri it redirects upto access page, But when I click on 'Allow', it displays error and not redirecting to the activity where I define intent filter.

I am facing issue with redirect_uri. I don't have any server so i put redirect_uri as ******://logincallback

```
      <activity android:name=".ChromeCustomTabActivity">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="logincallback"
            android:scheme="******" />
    </activity>
```

[image]

[image]

**SOLVED**

```
<activity android:name=".ChromeCustomTabActivity">
       <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data
            android:host="logincallback"
            android:scheme="******" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Ehy dear, can you post code? I really interested in this part but  I m new in android and I m really stuck.

Comment: Code is not available due to privacy matters

Comment: Can I know what is the host and scheme really means and what values need to be added for them?

Answer (score 1):

The redirect_uri must be an exact match one of the values specified in your application settings(Callback URL). And Callback URL should be a public API that is accessible by fitbit, that can be a website url hosted locally in your system.

Check this:

https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/#redirect-uris

Comment: means?
if I put resirect uri as 'myapplication://logincallback' then the same should be in callback URL. Righ?

Comment: If you area ware with FitBit API integration can you provide code snippet and example fitbit callback URL?

Comment: I don't have code snippet. Your callback url should be a public url.

Comment: public API that is accessible by fitbit, that can be a website url hosted locally in your system...What does this mean?

Comment: can you update what is the url in address bar after clicking allow and error you are getting clearly.

Comment: It is solved, Manifest <intent-filter> tag was missing

silly mistake by myself.....

Comment: @NikitaShah it seems you found the answer to your question. Could you post it as an answer to your question, so it can be marked as the correct answer?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.It is written after "SOLVED". If not getting let me know